# Alternative to command line for short path names

Tags: matlab, filenames, filepath

There is a specific case where having "path with space" doesn't work and I need to get the Windows short path names (e.g. Program Files = Progra~1 and Program Files (x86) = Progra~2).

Here what I'm doing for now :

```
[status, PATHROOT] = dos([ ...
    'for %A in ("' ...
    myPathWithSpace ...
    '") do @echo %~sA' ...
    ]);
```

Now, I tried using `regexp` and `regexprep` to format the file path, but it fails in some case to reproduce the `dos` short names. So how can I reproduce the `dos` command with MATLAB commands?

And here my ugly try with `regexp` and `regexprep`:

```
PATHROOT = regexprep(regexprep(regexp(myPathWithSpace,'\w:\\\w*\s\w*\\.*','match'),'\s', ''),'(\w:\\\w{6})\w*','$1~1');
```

Comment: What did your try with `regexp` and `regexprep`, and what problem did you have?

Comment: @SamRoberts I added what I've did with 'regexp' and 'regexprep'. I didn't post it in the original post as it is quite ugly and doesn't give the good short path name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function:

function shortPath = getshortpath(longPath)

fs = actxserver('Scripting.FileSystemObject');

shortPath = fs.GetFolder(longPath).ShortPath;

fs.delete;

Comment: That is quite leet! I tested with `tic` and `toc` and your solution is almost 10 times faster compared to the `dos` command. Can you actually replace all `dos` commands with an actxserver?